# How do you build an MSIX package from the command line

Tags: windows, powershell, package-management

My end goal is to be able to run a Powershell install script in a VM and capture all the changes it makes into a MSIX package. I can do this manually without issue using the MSIX Packaging Tool wizard, but I have a lot of apps to package and some of them update frequently, so I would like to get something automated going.

I have tried using the [batch conversion script](https://github.com/microsoft/MSIX-Toolkit/tree/master/Scripts/BatchConversion) with the following settings in entry.ps1:

```
$virtualMachines = @(
    @{ Name = "MSIX Packaging Tool Environment"; Credential = $credential }
)

$remoteMachines = @(
)

$conversionsParameters = @(
    @{
        InstallerPath = "Cricut Design Space.msi";
        PackageName = "CricutDesignSpace";
        PackageDisplayName = "Cricut Design Space";
        PublisherName = "CN=Cricut";
        PublisherDisplayName = "Cricut";
    }
)
```

Which just tells me all jobs have finished and produces no MSIX files.

I have also tried manually creating this template:

```
<MsixPackagingToolTemplate
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/msixpackagingtool/template/2018"
  xmlns:mptv2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/msix/msixpackagingtool/template/1904">
<Installer
  Path="L:\Work\scratch\batch-msix-builder\Cricut Design Space.msi"
  Arguments="" />
<VirtualMachine Name="MSIX Packaging Tool Environment" Username="user" />
<SaveLocation PackagePath="L:\Work\scratch\batch-msix-builder" />
<PackageInformation
  PackageName="CricutDesignSpace"
  PackageDisplayName="CricutDesignSpace"
  PublisherName="CN=Cricut"
  PublisherDisplayName="Cricut"
  Version="5.9.8.0" />
</PackageInformation>
</MsixPackagingToolTemplate>
```

and running it with

```
MsixPackagingTool.exe create-package --template "L:\Work\scratch\batch-msix-builder\template.xml" --virtualMachinePassword "REDACTED"
```

This causes a console window to open for a fraction of a second and immediately close. I have even tried this on a fresh install of windows to see if it was something with my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on this for more than a day, and of course as soon as I post online I discovered what was going wrong.

The main issue was MsixPackagingTool.exe doesn't seem to work when I let it prompt for elevation as opposed to explicitly running it from an administrative PowerShell window. Additionally I had some malformed XML. Once I started running from an elevated command prompt I was able to actually see the errors output by MsixPackagingTool.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer (can't comment as I'm not that much a member here) but as a remark, this link might help interested parties e.g. at the template creation starts

[How to generate a template file for command line conversions - MSIX | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/generate-template-file)

(Somewhere along the quoted lines at the very end as suggested by @djdomi.)

For those assessing possible complications related to MSIX-ification, making the package a startup-capable task
[might be involving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866597/how-to-specify-autostart-extension-node-in-an-msix-installer-package-template).

---

> With the MSIX Packaging Tool, you can perform the conversion in two
> ways: through the interactive UI or through our command line option.
> When using the command line, you need to provide a template file so
> that the conversion works with your specific settings and needs. This
> article will help guide you through the process of generating a
> template file that works for you.
>
> There are two ways that you can get a template file that works for
> you:
>
> - You can use the UI of the MSIX Packaging Tool. In the settings of the tool, you can specify that you want to generate a conversion
>   template file with each MSIX package that you create.
> - You can take a [sample template](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/generate-template-file#sample-conversion-template-file)
>   and manually enter the configurations that you need for each
>   conversion.
>
> ### Generate a conversion template file from the MSIX Packaging Tool
>
> 1. Launch the MSIX Packaging Tool.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/502130)

Comment: I wouldn't like to publish my opinion about MSIX/Partner Center at the minute but believe me I have already invested more time on it than it deserves as far as I could see it.

Anyway, your suggestion in general is realistic/good and as an appreciation I added some bits so that it can be more easily searched back etc.